# What to know when choosing a SSL Certificate

Tags: asp.net, ssl, ssl-certificate

I am in the market to purchase a SSL certificate/Web Hosting Service. This is the first SSL Cert I ever bought and looking to learn about them.  For a site that dumps its form data into a smtp request. I want this transmission to be encrypted.  Is they're any advice anyone could give me on purchasing the correct SSL certificate to accomplish something like that.
  Also if anyone had any recommended reading on this I would greatly appreciate it.

I am under the impression that I need this SSL Certificate from a previous question that I asked.

[How to send a Secure e-mail using SMTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11681026/how-to-send-a-secure-e-mail-using-smtp)

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://security.stackexchange.com/a/13614/2435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on what you're trying to accomplish.  If all you require is for traffic to be SSL encrypted, then one of the cheaper websites such as RapidSSL is fine.  These don't check that you are who you say you are, only that you have access to the domain you're buying the certificate for.  If you're running a site where you want your users to be sure they're dealing with who they think they are, then an EV SSL product from any of the major suppliers will turn the address bar green.  These products will require additional verification checks and take longer to issue.

Finally, the reseller prices on many of the major SSL products are significantly cheaper than retail - you'll probably get a better deal buying through a reseller than buying from one of the major brands directly, even though you'll be getting exactly the same product.

Comment: if i used a shared hosting service do i need to buy the certificate though the shared host or can i purchase it interdependently and if so it there a reason to buy it interdependently?

Comment: If you're using shared hosting, the important requirement is that you'll need a dedicated IP from them.  You don't have to buy a certificate from them at all, but they might be competitive on price so check.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some information you may find worth reading before getting your SSL-cert.

[important-things-you-should-know-before-installing-an-ssl-certificate](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/ssl-certificates/important-things-you-should-know-before-installing-an-ssl-certificate)

i tried to put this in a comment but the option wasn't there for some reason. Anyway, hope it helps!

Comment: What is said on that link isn't completely accurate. You don't necessarily need a dedicated IP address if you can use SNI, and certs don't have to be issued on an annual basis (there is no limit in the specs and some CAs do it for 2 years).

Comment: @ richard thank you for your post your link actually brought me to another link where i found some good information i think. http://support.hostgator.com/articles/what-type-of-ssl-secure-certificate-do-i-need